# Check if bash script already running except itself with arguments

Tags: bash

So I've looked up other questions and answers for this and as you can imagine, there are lots of ways to find this. However, my situation is kind of different.

I'm able to check whether a bash script is already running or not and I want to kill the script if it's already running.

The problem is that with the below code, -since I'm running this within the same script- the script kills itself too because it sees a script already running.

```sh
result=`ps aux | grep -i "myscript.sh" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
if [ $result -ge 1 ]
   then
        echo "script is running"
   else
        echo "script is not running"
fi
```

So how can I check if a script is already running besides it's own self and kill itself if there's another instance of the same script is running, else, continue without killing itself.

I thought I could combine the above code with `$$` command to find the script's own `PID` and differentiate them this way but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also a side note, my script can be run multiple times at the same time within the same machine but with different arguments and that's fine. I only need to identify if script is already running **with the same arguments**.

Comment: How about using a `watchdog` kind of file? Make a lock file before kicking off the script and delete it after its successful execution. In between check condition if its present if yes then leave the script from running or kick it off again.

Comment: maybe just `flock`? + `lsof` to find the pid

Answer (score 1):

I would go with either of 2 ways to solve this problem.

***1st solution:*** Create a watchdog file lets say a .lck file kind of on a location before starting the script's execution(Make sure we use `trap` etc commands in case script is aborted so that .lck file should be removed) AND remove it once execution of script is completed successfully.

***Example script for 1st solution:*** This is just an example a test one. We need to take care of interruptions in the script, lets say script got interrupted by a command or etc then we could use `trap` in it too, since at that time it would have not been completed but you may need to kick it off again(since last time it was not completed).

```
cat file.ksh
#!/bin/bash
PWD=`pwd`
watchdog_file="$PWD/script.lck"

if [[ -f "$watchdog_file" ]]
then
    echo "Please wait script is still running, exiting from script now.."
    exit 1;
else
    touch $watchdog_file
fi
while true
do
  echo "singh" > test1
done

if [[ -f "$watchdog_file" ]]
then
    rm "$watchdog_file"
fi
```

***2nd solution:*** Take pid of current running shell using `$$` save it in a file. Then check if that process is still running come out of script if NOT running then move on to run statements in script.

Comment: 1st solution makes sense. Can you expand it more with examples?

Comment: @MarryJane, sure I just came for tea will write in some time.

Comment: @MarryJane, I have added a very simple example(it is example of an infinite loop so be aware), for understanding purposes only, cheers. Lemme know in case of any queries here.

Comment: Thank you. Though, I'm still not sure how can I include the arguments of the running bash script.

Comment: @MarryJane, trust me you could add it easily, add lines from my code from 3rd line to 11(paste these before executing main statements in your script initial phase may be after variables declaration). Then copy last four lines(place these at last your script) . You could do a test in non-prod environment first and try it out please do lemme know whererver I could help will be happy to guide cheers.

Comment: I tried and it works but the thing is that my script can be run multiple times with different arguments and I don't want to check for that. I only want to check if the arguments are the same. This option doesn't help with that part of my goal.

Comment: @MarryJane, But this is not related to any argument checking this is simply to avoid multiple runs of script at a time, so you need to write these few lines in starting and end of the script only.

Comment: I see. But what I'm looking for is that I need to check and avoid multiple runs of script at a time with the same arguments but not with different arguments as I stated in my question. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @MarryJane, yeah didn't know that, will write it in few hours. As its mid night here and post to you, cheers :)

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pid=$(pgrep myscript.sh | grep -x -v $$)

# filter non-existent pids
pid=$(<<<"$pid" xargs -n1 sh -c 'kill -0 "$1" 2>/dev/null && echo "$1"' --)

if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    echo "Other script is running with pid $pid"
    echo "Killing him!"
    kill $pid
fi
```

`pgrep` lists the pids that match the name `myscript.sh`. From the list we filter current `$$` shell with `grep -v`. It the result is non-empty, then you could kill the other pid.

Without the `xargs`, it would work, but the `pgrep myscript.sh` will pick up the temporary pid created for command substitution or the pipe. So the `pid` will never be empty and the `kill` will always execute complaining about the non-existent process. To do that, for each pid in pids, I check if the pid exists with `kill -0`. If it does, then it is outputted, effectively filtering all nonexistent pids.

You could also use a normal `for` loop to filter the pids:

```
# filter non-existent pids
pid=$(
        for i in $pid; do
                if kill -0 "$i" 2>/dev/null; then
                        echo "$i"
                fi
        done
)
```

Alternatively, you could use `flock` to lock the file and use `lsof` to list current open files with filtering the current one. As it is now, I think it will kill also editors that are editing the file and such. I believe the `lsof` output could be better filtered to accommodate this.

```
if [ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ]; then 
        pids=$(lsof -p "^$$" -- ./myscript.sh  | awk 'NR>1{print $2}')
        if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
                echo "Other processes with $(echo $pids) found. Killing them"
                kill $pids
        fi
        exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. First option seems convenient. Although, it's killing the previously running script. Instead, it should kill itself, not the previous script.

Comment: It is also not differentiating the arguments. If I run a script with some argument like `myscript.sh arg1` and then run it again with different argument like `myscript.sh arg2` it still says "Other script is running with pid" but it shouldn't do that if the arguments are different.

Comment: Then change the `pgrep` into the common atipattern `ps aux | grep ... | grep -v grep`, or use ex. [soemthing like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106568/how-to-check-the-process-along-with-its-arguments-in-process-list), like `pgrep -af myscript.sh` and compare arguments, etc.